# In WordPress, I cannot upload image on Mac

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, media

I'm newbie on WordPress. But I cannot upload photo in media section, I got an error like this "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2017/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to reset the permissions on the 'media' folder via FTP Client.

[Link](http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/wordpress/navigation-customization/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-filezilla-on-your-ftp-site/) how to do this with Filezilla..

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)